# cfmail is not formatting css

Tags: css, email, coldfusion, html-email, cfmail

Firstly apologies with my limited knowledge, I am just starting out in CF.

So I am trying to send out an html email with cfmail when a form query is satisfied.

The problem I am having is that the css I am embedding within the email head is either throwing up errors or just not formatting at all. Please could someone look at my code and tell me where I am going wrong.

Incidentally when I take out the # tags in the css it seems to work but the email sends with no formatting!!!

```
    <cfmail to="customer email" from="xxxxxxx@gmail.com" subject="Your order at has been shipped" type="html">
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Title</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
body, td, th, input, textarea, select, a {
    font-size: 12px;
}
p {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
a, a:visited, a b {
    color: #378DC1;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a img {
    border: none;
}
#container {
    width: 680px;
}
#logo {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
table.list {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-left: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
table.list td {
    border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}
table.list thead td {
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    padding: 0px 5px;
}
table.list thead td a, .list thead td {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #222222;
    font-weight: bold;
}
table.list tbody td a {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
table.list tbody td {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0px 5px;
}
table.list .left {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 7px;
}
table.list .right {
    text-align: right;
    padding: 7px;
}
table.list .center {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 7px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <p>Your Order has been Shipped</p>
  <table class="list">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td class="left" colspan="2">text_order_detail;</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="left"><b>text_order_id</b><br />
          <b>text_date_added</b><br />
          <b>text_payment_method</b><br />
          <b>text_shipping_method</b>
          </td>
        <td class="left"><b>text_email</b><br />
          <b>text_telephone</b><br />
          <b>text_ip<br /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
    <table class="list">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td class="left">text_instruction</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="left">comment</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="list">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td class="left">text_payment_address</td>
        <td class="left">text_shipping_address</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="left">payment_address</td>
        <td class="left">shipping_address</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="list">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td class="left">text_product</td>
        <td class="left">text_model</td>
        <td class="right">text_quantity</td>
        <td class="right">text_price</td>
        <td class="right">text_total</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="left">product
          <br />
          <small>option</small>
 </td>
        <td class="left">product['model']</td>
        <td class="right">product['quantity']</td>
        <td class="right">product['price']</td>
        <td class="right">product['total']</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="right"><b>total['title']</b></td>
        <td class="right">total['text']</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
  <p>text_footer</p>
  <p>text_powered</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
    </cfmail>
        </cfif>
```

Comment: you want to use ## instead of #

Comment: In which mailclients are you having these issue? All? MS Outlook, Mozilla Thunderbird, GoogleMail, ...?

Comment: @Seybsen: I expect it's not a mail client thing at all. Raw pound signs are variable markers in ColdFusion, hence the need to escape them (by doubling them) when you actually want one to output. Otherwise you'll get errors because a variable can't be found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should stick to inline styles for HTML emails rather than having your styles presented the way you are doing.

E.G.

```
<td style="padding:10px;"></td>
```

Comment: I have converted to inline but still the same problems :-(

Answer (score 4):

Two issues the first is you need to use `##` in your CSS instead of `#`, otherwise     ColdFusion tries to process those as variables. The second is you have an erroneous `</cfif>` at the bottom of your page, but that was probably just from when you copy and pasted your code.

I tested the code with `##` instead of `#` and the email sent correctly on CF 9.0.1

Comment: The lack of using ## should not be an issue here as the # are not within a CFOUTPUT so ColdFusion will NOT try to process them. Also, if this were the issue, ColdFusion would throw an error or, at the very least, not send the email.

Comment: Like the OP said, it does throw an error. `cfmail` functions as a `cfoutput`, you don't need to use a `cfoutput` tag inside `cfmail`

Comment: Wow - I really need to not read SO right after waking. By bad. Carry on folks...nothing to see here.....